# Python MiniGame struggling

Tags: python, matrix

I am struggling with this python program.
The goal is simple, a minigame with a map and a player, you move the player wit the zqsd keys and have to move through the map. The thing is I'm lost at an early task I need to code which is the following:
-Make sure that the player doesn't get out of the map by modifying the update_p function and add the map parameter in it.

Not sure how to make it , any help would be really great.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import sys

#Carte

m=[[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
m2=m
m3=[]
d={0 : ' ', 1 : '#' }
def display_map(m,d):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m[i])):
            if m[i][j]==0:
                m[i][j]=d[0]
            elif m[i][j]==1:
                m[i][j]=d[1]
    for h in range(len(m)):
        print(*m[h], sep="")
    return ""

#Personnage

depart=(0,0)

def create_perso(x,y):
    p={ "char" : "o", "x" : x , "y" : y }
    return p
p=create_perso(0,0)

def display_map_and_char(m,d,p):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m[i])):
            if m[i][j]==0:
                m[i][j]=d[0]
            elif m[i][j]==1:
                m[i][j]=d[1]
    m2=m
    for i in range(len(m2)):
        for j in range(len(m2[i])):
            if m2[i][j]=='o':
                m2[i][j]=" "           
    list=[]
    for k in p.values():
        list+=[k]
    if list[0]=='o':
        pos=p
        if list[1]<=(len(m)) and list[2]<=len(m):
            m2[list[1]][list[2]]=list[0]
    m3=np.concatenate((m,m2))
    for h in range(len(m)):
        print(*m3[h], sep="")
    return ""

letter=input()

def update_p(letter,p,m):
    if m[p["x"]][p["y"]]:
        if letter=="d":
            p["y"]=p["y"]+1
        if letter=="z":
            p["x"]=p["x"]-1
        if letter=="q":
            p["y"]=p["y"]-1
        if letter=="s":
            p["x"]=p["x"]+1
        return ""

while True:
    letter=input()
    print(update_p(letter,p,m))
    print(display_map_and_char(m,d,p))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that are not enough information from you to make a god answer (what are the menaings of 0s and 1s and that stuff). But if you only want to add a boundary check for the map you have to check if `0 < x < map_width` and `0 < y < map_height` like this:

```
def update_p(letter,p,m):
    if m[p["x"]][p["y"]]:
        if letter=="d":
            if p["y"]+1 <= len(m):
                p["y"]=p["y"]+1
        if letter=="z":
            if p["x"]-1 >= 0:
                p["x"]=p["x"]-1
        if letter=="q":
            p["y"]=p["y"]-1  # up to you
        if letter=="s":
            p["x"]=p["x"]+1  # up to you
        return ""
```

This is a very basic question, maybe you take an easier tutorial

Comment: Your position checks are backwards.

Answer (score 0):

In `update_p`, you are adding or removing 1 from the current x or y position based on the key pressed. You want to check beforehand whether the new position will be outside the map.

```
def update_p(letter, p, m):
    map_size = len(m[0]) # Your map is square so we don't need anything fancier than that.
    if letter == "d" and 0 <= p["y"] + 1 <= map_size:
        p["y"] = p["y"] + 1
    elif letter == "z" and 0 <= p["x"] - 1 <= map_size:
        p["x"] = p["x"] - 1
    elif letter == "q" and 0 <= p["y"] - 1 <= map_size:
        p["y"] = p["y"] - 1
    elif letter == "s" and 0 <=  p["x"] + 1 <= map_size:
        p["x"] = p["x"] + 1
    return ""
```

Unrelated to your question, by I don't see why you represent the player as a dictionary instead of using a custom class.

```
def create_perso(x,y):
    p={ "char" : "o", "x" : x , "y" : y }
    return p
p=create_perso(0,0)
```

Should be

```
class Personnage:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.char = "o"
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
p = Personnage(0, 0)
```

Which means this

```
list=[]
for k in p.values():
    list+=[k]
if list[0]=='o':
    pos=p
    if list[1]<=(len(m)) and list[2]<=len(m):
        m2[list[1]][list[2]]=list[0]
```

has to be modified into this:

```
if p.x <= len(m) and p.y <= len(m):
    m2[p.x][p.y] = p.char
```

Then we can come back to `update_p` and make it more compact:

```
def update_p(letter, p, m):
    map_size = len(m[0]) # Your map is square so we don't need anything fancier than that.
    if   letter == "d" and 0 <= p.y + 1 <= map_size:
        p.y += 1
    elif letter == "z" and 0 <= p.x - 1 <= map_size:
        p.x -= 1
    elif letter == "q" and 0 <= p.y - 1 <= map_size:
        p.y -= 1
    elif letter == "s" and 0 <=  p.x + 1 <= map_size:
        p.x += 1
    return ""
```

Finally, you could also add another check to see if the next position on the map is already occupied by a wall and prevent the character from moving there.